# Two dimensional array into a pointer

Tags: c, function, pointers, arguments

I define a structure that I call `Neuron`.

In my main, I create a two dimensional array:

```
 Neuron N_network[4][10]; //create a neural network
```

I have a function to print the structure element:

```
void print_stat_neuron(Neuron * neuron_info)
```

What should I write to print `N_network[i][j]` (as an argument of the `print_stat_neuron()` function)?
I try simply with `&(N_network[i][j])` and I get an error message.

I have the fallowing error message with the compiler gcc -Wall -Wextra:

```
2ex4.c: In function 'init_network':
2ex4.c:168:2: warning: implicit declaration of function'print_stat_neuron' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
print_stat_neuron(&N_network[4][1]);
^
2ex4.c: At top level:
2ex4.c:191:6: warning: conflicting types for 'print_stat_neuron' [enabled by default]
void print_stat_neuron(Neuron * neuron_info)
  ^
2ex4.c:168:2: note: previous implicit declaration of 'print_stat_neuron' was here
 print_stat_neuron(&N_network[4][1]);
```

Comment: What is the error message?  It is always helpful to see the text of the error message;  it isn't necessarily helpful to see the whole file name if it is ten directories deep (but the base name of the file is sensible).

Comment: You also need to place a function declaration earlier on in your code than the first time you call the function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the parameter to `Neuron (*neuron_info)[10]`. Now you can call this function as

```
print_stat_neuron(N_network);
```

or

```
print_stat_neuron(&N_network[0]);
```

Comment: I don't want to use the all array but just a single element.

Comment: Why would that be necessary?

Comment: Sure but I can always do it an other way but I was curious.

Answer (score 2):

The error messages you show come from not declaring the function before using it, so the compiler deduces a type for the function (`extern int print_stat_neuron();` with no specification for the number or types of the parameters), and then objects to you defining it with a return type of `void`.  Note that in C, `extern int print_stat_neuron();` is not a prototype for a function with no arguments; that's `extern int print_stat_neuron(void);`.

This code compiles cleanly:

```
typedef struct Neuron
{
    int x;
} Neuron;

void print_stat_neuron(Neuron *neuron_info);

int main(void)
{
    Neuron N_network[4][10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
            print_stat_neuron(&N_network[i][j]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This declares the function before using it.  It would also be acceptable to define the function before using it (which saves having a separate declaration).  Of course, if the function will be used outside the source file where it is defined, it should have a declaration in a header, and the header should be used both where it is defined and where it is used.  If the function is not used outside the source file where it is defined, it should be `static`.

Clean compilation checked with GCC 5.3.0 on Mac OS X 10.10.5 (my El Capitan machine is under warranty repair, unfortunately):

```
$ gcc -std=c11 -O3 -g -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
>     -Wold-style-definition -c neuron.c
$
```